# correctly install openbr on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: qt, opencv, ubuntu, openbr

I've been trying to install openbr on an ubuntu 18.04 digitalocean droplet.

Here's the latest process I've gotten going:

```
# --opencv install and build--
# installs opencv 2.4
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt install -y \
                build-essential \
                cmake \
                git \
                pkg-config \
                libgtk-3-dev \
                libavcodec-dev \
                libavformat-dev \
                libswscale-dev \
                libv4l-dev \
                libxvidcore-dev \
                libx264-dev \
                libjpeg-dev \
                libpng-dev \
                libtiff-dev \
                gfortran \
                openexr \
                libatlas-base-dev \
                python3-dev \
                python3-numpy \
                libtbb2 \
                libtbb-dev \
                libdc1394-22-dev

mkdir ~/opencv_build && cd ~/opencv_build
git clone --single-branch --branch 2.4 https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git

cd ~/opencv_build/opencv
mkdir build && cd build

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..

make -j6

sudo make install



# --qt install--

sudo apt-get update

# Installs qt version 5.9.5 as of 1 Apr 2020
sudo apt-get install -y qt5-default libqt5svg5-dev qtcreator



# --openbr install and build--

# download & prep openbr
git clone https://github.com/biometrics/openbr.git
cd openbr
git checkout v1.1.0
git submodule init
git submodule update

# build openbr
mkdir build # from the OpenBR root directory
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
make -j6
sudo make install
```

This builds to the point where i can test openbr's example:

`$ br -algorithm FaceRecognition -compare me.jpg you.jpg`

I receive this error when running the above line with any images:

```
Set algorithm to FaceRecognition
Loading /usr/local/share/openbr/models/algorithms/FaceRecognition
Fatal: Failed to set br::Transform* br::IndependentTransform::transform to: 
  SDK Path: /usr/local
  File: 
  Function: 
  Line: 0
```

From what I understand, this is because I have the wrong version of qt. Openbr wants 5.4.1, but the earliest I've managed to install is 5.9.5.

It may have been more correct to say my question is how to install qt5.4.1. In the end though, all I'm after is a reliable and repeatable way to get openbr running on ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: You say: *From what I understand, this is because I have the wrong version of qt. Openbr wants 5.4.1, but the earliest I've managed to install is 5.9.5.*, Why do you point that out? clearly openbr is being compiled with the system Qt

Comment: Qt is one of the dependencies for openbr, & they specify using Qt5.4.1 in their documentation. There is also this issue on their github: https://github.com/biometrics/openbr/issues/468 that talks about the issue I'm running into being connected to using a version of Qt that openbr doesn't work with. Qt depreciated all the versions that openbr supports from what I can tell. I haven't been able to install an earlier version than qt5.9.5.

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this same issue trying to run OpenBR on Ubuntu 18.  Your diagnosis is correct, its a QT version issue.  The fix got merged into the OpenBR master [here](https://github.com/biometrics/openbr/pull/486/files) but is not on the 2.4 branch.  If you apply that edit to what is on the 2.4 and re-run the build steps, it worked on my box.  Steps below:

1. Open openbr/openbr/openbr_plugin.cpp
2. Originally, line 1620 reads `independent.set("transform", qVariantFromValue<void*>(transform));`
3. Replace it with `independent.set("transform", QVariant::fromValue(transform));`
4. Rerun the build steps from inside your build folder.

Hope that works.  Thanks.